# Making AJAX Post Requst to PHP Routine to Local File

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl

I have an AJAX request file that looks like this:

```js
$.ajax({
        url: 'libs/php/getCountryBorder.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            name: 'Bahamas',
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
    });
```

I also have a geojson file that looks like this:

You can view my local geojson file here [Geojson File](https://stephenorowole.co.uk/vendors/countryBorder/countryBorders.geo.json)

[image]

Here is my PHP routine call to the local file geo.json file:

```
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $url = 'https://stephenorowole.co.uk/vendors/countryBorder/countryBorders.geo.json?&name=' . $_REQUEST['name'];

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $jsonResponse = json_decode($response, true);

  $output['data'] = $jsonResponse['features'];
  header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
  echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

So, I made an Ajax call from another file to the php to get only a specific name in the json file. It doesn't return only the name data but all the data in the json file. What I want is a specific data in the json to be returned through the request.
I don't know how to do this with local file. It's easy for me to do if I'm working with external API.

In external API, if a request is made to return only the country that matches a specific latitude and longitude, the specific data will be returned for that specific request. However, I don't know how to achieve this when I'm working with a local file.

I want to be able to get geometry of a country based on the name of the country given as a request data when I make the call. I've just added the ajax call.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're going to have to do the data extraction yourself. i.e. loop through the records to find the one you want.

Comment: Ok, assuming I want to have an ajax get the list of names separate and another ajax request to get the geometry specific to that name, do I need to create different php files for each request.

Comment: Please add your code to the question as text rather than images of your code

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a local (complete) json file locally which serves as a *local DB*, you will have to manually build your result json.

I am not sure I grasped what you were trying to achieve, would you be able to share your calls?

Is there a reason why you don't call the API directly in your Ajax call? It doesn't seem you are doing much in your PHP call...

Comment: I want to be able to get geometry of a country based on the name of the country given as a request data when I make the call. I've just added the ajax call

Comment: Added a comment here. Why don't you call the API directly in your ajax call? You don't seem to do much in your php and it would simplify the logic. As I said, if you do not want to call the API multiple time but leverage a json file you have stored on your server, you have no choice but to loop over it and build a response manually, which I would discourage.

Comment: I'm just following a guidline from my tutor. Even though I make the call directly, I still need to find a way make a request based on a specific name e.g, Canada

Comment: It's not clear at.this point how we can help you. What are you seeing when you run the code?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, it return the whole json data

Comment: What do you send (what is the url sent)? Do you retrieve the country name as you would expect?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, making a request to local file with a set parameter can't work since the is no backend code writing to handle an http get resquest for the specific data.
I can only get a specific data from a local json file by adding to my php code above.

Here is my new complete php code that get the specific data from the geojson file:

```js
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $url = 'https://stephenorowole.co.uk/vendors/countryBorder/countryBorders.geo.json';

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $jsonResponse = json_decode($response, true);


 $output = null;
  foreach($jsonResponse['features'] as $data){
    if($data['properties']['name'] == $_REQUEST['name']){
      $output['data'] = $data;
      break; 
    };
  };

  header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
  echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

This is the code snipet in the php file that did the trick:

````
  foreach($jsonResponse['features'] as $data){
    if($data['properties']['name'] == $_REQUEST['name']){
      $output['data'] = $data;
      break; 
    };
  };```
````